# pandas: concat multiple dataframes while not ignoring the indexes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've three dataframes:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 50, (3,3)), columns = ["A", "B", "C"], index = ["1", "2", "3"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 50, (4,2)), columns = ["D", "E"], index = ["100", "101", "102", "103"])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (11,5)), columns = ["F", "G", "H", "I", "J"], index = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "100", "101", "102", "103"])
```

and I want to concat these dataframes in

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"])
```

Now while using

```
df5 = pd.concat([df5, df2])
df5 = pd.concat([df5, df3])
df5 = pd.concat([df5, df4])
```

it creates multiple 1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 101, 102, and 103 indexes. I don't want it to do that. Ideally, I want value for FGHIJ to be pasted in first index 1 and likewise for index 2, 3, 4, 100, 101, 102, 103. Can anyone please help?

[OutputDataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBt93.jpg)

Comment: Is `pd.concat([df2, df3, df4], axis='columns')` what you want?

Comment: Oh no! this is not what I want. If I would have, I could have applied axis = 'columns'. I want to concat on index/rows, without duplicating the indexes.

Comment: Calling concat that way with your data does not duplicate any indexes.

Comment: @Goyo I think your solution is correct.  I posted an example below showing how concat performs under these conditions.  If this is not what the OP wants then this needs to be made more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to join the dataframes other than concatenating them.

```
df5 = df4.join([df2, df3])
```

The default of the join function is to use the **index** as a column to perform the join operation.

Comment: I think this should work, I've just asked for three dataframes here. The actual number of dataframes are 14. Let me try using this starting with the dataframe with maximum number of rows and then joining them with others so that we don't get duplicates.

Comment: with join there is one problem, I get: Indexes have overlapping values: [u'D', u'E', u'F', u'G', u'H', u'I', u'J']. Why is that?

Comment: @greenarrow Again, I am unable to duplicate your error.  Can you please update your post to indicate which versions of Python and Pandas you are using?

Answer (score 0):

What versions of Python and Pandas as you using?  I am using Python 3.6 and Pandas 22 and I am not able to replicate your problem.  Here is what I did.

From your post

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 50, (3,3)), columns = ["A", "B", "C"], index = ["1", "2", "3"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 50, (4,2)), columns = ["D", "E"], index = ["100", "101", "102", "103"])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (11,5)), columns = ["F", "G", "H", "I", "J"], index = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "100", "101", "102", "103"])
```

Now the solution (identical to Goyo's comment...which seems to work!):

```
df5 = pd.concat([df2, df3, df4], axis=1)
```

This gives:

```
        A     B     C     D     E    F    G    H    I    J
1    38.0   2.0  25.0   NaN   NaN  886  767  281  771  980
100   NaN   NaN   NaN  42.0  30.0  305  986  192  554  697
101   NaN   NaN   NaN   2.0  45.0  581  910  767  513  758
102   NaN   NaN   NaN  31.0  21.0  767  102  825   90  904
103   NaN   NaN   NaN  32.0  35.0  342    3  293  549  506
2    22.0   8.0  26.0   NaN   NaN  140  697  705  289  330
3    28.0  46.0  32.0   NaN   NaN  672  928  503  406  903
4     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  298  306  122  115  323
5     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  937  702  732  677   60
6     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  276  869  812  552  299
7     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  445  288  107   66  165
```

From what I can tell from your original post this is what you want.  Is this what you want or not?  The only problem I see here with this dataframe is the index is not sorted.  This can be solved by calling df5.sort_index.

If this is not what you want then please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As I said earlier, the dataframes asked in original question were a part of a problem. Actually I had 14 different dataframes, which I extracted from a 2 pager PDF using Tabula package. The actual PDF had 7 dataframes on each of the page with same column headers. For now let's not go into how I extracted using Tabula and focus on the dataframes. Someone just asked for python version, I used Python 2.7.

Dataframes:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 250, (4,3)), columns = ["A", "B", "C"], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 250, (4,2)), columns = ["D", "E"], index = [100, 101, 102, 103])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5000, (11,5)), columns = ["F", "G", "H", "I", "J"], index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 100, 101, 102, 103])
df5 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 300, (4,2)), columns = ["N", "O"], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
df6 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 250, (4,3)), columns = ["P", "Q", "R"], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
df7 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5000, (7,3)), columns = ["K", "L", "M"], index = [1, 2, 3, 100, 101, 102, 103])
df8 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 300, (4,1)), columns = ["S"], index = [100, 101, 102, 103])
df9 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 400, (4,3)), columns = ["A", "B", "C"], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
df10 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 250, (4,2)), columns = ["D", "E"], index = [100, 101, 102, 103])
df11 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5000, (11,5)), columns = ["F", "G", "H", "I", "J"], index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
df12 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 500, (4,2)), columns = ["N", "O"], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
df13 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 600, (4,3)), columns = ["P", "Q", "R"], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
df14 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 700, (4,1)), columns = ["S"], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
df15 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5000, (7,3)), columns = ["K", "L", "M"], index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7])
```

I wanted to concat these dataframes on rows and not column. So first I created a concated dataframe to identify the list of unique indexes:

```
df16 = pd.concat([df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12, df13, df15, df14], axis = "columns")
```

then,

```
df18 = pd.DataFrame(index = list(df16.index.unique()))
df19 = pd.DataFrame(index = list(df16.index.unique()))
```

The idea to create two empty column dataframes was to avoid error on duplicate column. Then as @amr keleg (thanks!) suggested and I went on to join the dataframes (df2....df8) from first page into df18 and second page into (df9...df15). Now it got simpler:

```
df18 = df18.join([df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8])
df19 = df19.join([df9, df10, df11, df12, df13, df14, df15])
```

Now using pd.concat to concat the above two dataframes to arrive at the desired solution:

```
df20 = pd.concat([df18, df19])
df20.sort_index(axis = 0, inplace = True, ascending = True)
```

I'm not an expert in Python. I'm just a learner! For those with better solution to these can help.